# wercker with docker switching user results in error, how to install nvm then?

Tags: docker, wercker

**Problem**

My wercker build exits with `Failed step: setup environment - Command exited with exit code: 1` when I'm switching user in my Docker image. I'm running `wercker dev` from the commandline. The Dockerfile builds fine with Docker itself on the commandline, as well as on Docker Hub. I can run it fine. It's just when I use it for wercker, that the error occurs.

For example in my Dockerfile is the following code:

```
# Adding user 
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' dockworker && adduser dockworker sudo && echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
RUN mkdir -p /home/dockworker && chown -R dockworker:dockworker /home/dockworker
USER dockworker # Line the build seems to break on
```

When I comment this line out, it seems to pass. Now the problem with this, for me, is the following: I'd like to switch to another user, since I'm trying to install `nvm` (for `gulp`, `bower`). Generally I don't prefer to install this this as root, therefore I add a user for this.

**Workaround?**

However, when I do install `nvm` as root in my Dockerfile (so just removing the user related lines in the codeblock above completely):

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 0.12.7
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm

# NVM
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.4/install.sh | NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm bash

#install the specified node version and set it as the default one, install the global npm packages
RUN . /usr/local/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install $NODE_VERSION && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION && npm install -g bower && npm install -g gulp
```

Then it does get past the `setup environment` stage, but during the steps it errors out that `nvm` and `npm` are not found. The step in the `wercker.yml`:

```
box:
    id: francobolli/docker-ubuntu-14.04-php-5.6
    tag: latest
    env:
        NVM_DIR: /usr/local/nvm
dev:
    steps:
      - script:
          name: gulp styles and javascript
          code: |
              npm install
              bower install --allow-root 
              gulp --env=production
```

I don't really understand this. When I run both docker images from the commandline (so with wercker removed from the context completely) I can execute `nvm` and `npm` just fine, but when I'm running it through wercker, it *seems* the `.bashrc` file is not being executed. When I `cat ~/.bashrc` during the steps, I can see:

```
export NVM_DIR="/usr/local/nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

**Workaround!**

When I enter this in a step, it will be executed and I can `npm install` without a problem, so it seems this is never executed through the `.bashrc`:

```
...
      - script:
          name: gulp styles and javascript
          code: |
              [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # It works when I put it here, but it's also in ~/.bashrc, which doesn't seem to get executed
              npm install
...
```

Note: If I `source ~/.bashrc` in the wercker step instead, it does not work.

**Question**

So my question is: What am I doing wrong, for not being able to switch user in the Wercker build and even if I could, would I have the same problem as running nvm with root: nvm and npm CAN be found when a Docker container is instantiated from the commandline, but CAN'T be found when running it with Wercker. What's the best solution?

I'd rather not add commands in the `wercker.yml` if it can be resolved through proper user configuration or proper nvm configuration. Sorry if I'm missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Docker configuration, but with how Wercker handles Docker boxes. From the documentation:

> #### Using Sudo
>
> The sudo command is no longer supported in wercker v2 and effectively does nothing when used.

And for deployment:

> Please note that if you update a project to make use of Docker (Ewok version) and this project has autodeployment, this deploy will most likely fail. We will update our documentation in the future on how to deploy these containers.

However, I did get it to build (and deploy) with the solution (temporary workaround?) as displayed in the original question.